# How can I perform this type of JOIN in Entity framework with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a class badge: (e.g)

```
**Badge**
 -User (Owned by)
 -Title (e.g votesOnThingReached5)
```

User's own badges through an class UserBadge, (it was required).

```
**UserBadge:**
  -User
  -Badge
```

So:

```
myUser.UserBadges(); //Gets all user's current badges they own.
db.Badges(); //Gets all badges avaialble to be earnt.
```

I need to only get the badges that the user doesn't currently have.

How can I write this LINQ? Here's my pseduo code example:

```
db.Badges(Where(b =>
new query(!myUser.UserBadges.contains(b));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Badges.Where(b=>!myUser.UserBadges.Contains(b));
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Users collection on your `Badge` POCO? If so:

`db.Badges.Where(b => !b.Users.Any(u=>u.UserId == myUserId));`

otherwise you can do:

```
List<int> ownedBadges = myUser.Badges.Select(x=> x.BadgeId).ToList();
db.Badges.Where(b => !ownedBadges.Contains(b.BadgeId));
```

Comment: need a `ToList()` after the `Select` call I think